# Font awesome icons displaying as blank squares on local server

Tags: node.js, express, font-awesome

I am getting blank squares instead of font awesome icons when trying to host the icons locally. Switching to the CDN hosted version works but I can't seem to get these served locally.

Here's my FA css include that does not work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Here's the CDN FA css include that does work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

I verified this file is being loaded correctly in the browser and has appropriate headers:

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Content-Type:text/css; charset=UTF-8
```

I'm trying to use the icons with the following html/css:

```
<a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home </a>
```

I can inspect this element and the applied styles look correct:

```
.fa{
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
}
....

.fa-home:before {
    content: "\f015";
}
```

The font file itself seems to be loaded correctly and with the correct headers, I know that content-type and CORS can be an issue here so I double checked these:

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:public, max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:65451
Content-Type:application/font-woff
Date:Wed, 12 Nov 2014 17:03:52 GMT
ETag:W/"ffab-105903352"
Last-Modified:Sun, 11 Nov 2014 17:31:23 GMT
X-Powered-By:Express
```

But still no luck. Again, switching to include the CDN file instead of hosting it locally and they render just fine. There are no other network or console errors elsewhere on the page, everything looks to be loaded correctly, but still getting blank squares. Using nodejs & express 4 on this local server if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

I tried many ways and the issue not fixed.
Then I found this in my stylesheet:

```
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, 'Microsoft YaHei' !important;
}
```

and it's all about that: **!important**,
remove it and everything works.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I don't use !important anywhere. I gave up on font awesome because I couldn't resolve this issue.

Comment: Maybe next time when you try it, check the styles on **computed**. I think that will give help.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, somebodey else, like me, has this problem at this time 2018. I had the same problem and as per I use local server, I COPIED the fonts folder (FontAwesome.otf, fontawesome.eot... svg... ttf... etc.to the testing server folder) (/httdocs in case of Mac).

Rememeber that if you set up your homesite files on a different folder, either a second hard drive or an external drive, when you try to test your php pages how do they look, those files will be copied AUTOMATICALLY to the testing server. BUT... some files are not copied automatically, like styles and fonts. All additional plug ins, I guess, must be copied previously in the test server to optimized to correct view of your pages during the test.

And of course, you need check and set up the correct path in the HTML file.